# How can I monitor LAN traffic on raspberry pi?

Tags: wireless, monitoring

I am trying to build a local network consisting of around 10-25 raspberry pis, each running on a static ip address. I wonder how I can monitor the traffic in the network. To be specific is there any tool I can use to monitor incoming and outgoing packets without generating extra network traffic?

Thanks a lot!

edit: Sorry that I might not have explained my question clearly. I am building an adhoc network with Pis only, no router. Each Pi communicates directly with other Pis. I want each Pi to monitor its own incoming and outgoing traffic to other Pis.

Comment: Note that to monitor packets on an WPA network the Pi's need to be logged in before anything else and stay so.

Comment: Is this a wired or wireless network?

Comment: @Craig This is wireless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most popular related project with GUI is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

> Wireshark is the world’s foremost and widely-used network protocol
>   analyzer. It lets you see what’s happening on your network at a
>   microscopic level and is the de facto (and often de jure) standard
>   across many commercial and non-profit enterprises, government
>   agencies, and educational institutions. Wireshark development thrives
>   thanks to the volunteer contributions of networking experts around the
>   globe and is the continuation of a project started by Gerald Combs in
>   1998.

`sudo apt-get install wireshark`

And without GUI you have [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) used by wireshark.

> TShark is a network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture packet data
>   from a live network, or read packets from a previously saved capture
>   file, either printing a decoded form of those packets to the standard
>   output or writing the packets to a file. TShark's native capture file
>   format is pcapng format, which is also the format used by wireshark
>   and various other tools.

`sudo apt-get install tshark`

Answer (score 2):

You can use tcpdump too. It may already be installed on your distro. It depends on how far you want to go into the analysis of captured packets.